# How to set different td sizes with inputs in them?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

[image]

However when I set the width of the td it never seems to change and I can only get it lo align to the length of the longest field like it is below:

[image]

What can I do to achieve the same results as with the image above?

Here is my code:

```
                  <table>

            <tr>
                <td class="no-wrap">Via (Jr, Av, Calle, Pje, Etc.):</td>
                <td class="send-right"><input type="text" size="5"></td>
                <td>Nombre Via:</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="25"></td>
                <td>Nro: <input type="text" size="5"></td>
                <td>Interior: <input type="text" size="7"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Tipo Zona</td>
                <td class="send-right"><input type="text" size="10"></td>
                <td>Nombre Zona:</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="20"></td>
                <td>Referencia:</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="18"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Departamento</td>
                <td class="send-right"><input type="text" size="15"></td>
                <td>Provincia:</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="20"></td>
                <td>Distrito:</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="18"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

```
.send-right {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't match the image at all; you only have one row. Please set up something that resembles the problem.

Comment: @wazz You are right. I have added all the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! You wrote `text-align: right;` when it should've been `text-align: end;`